# Banach spaces, how to show if a subspace is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

Is every subspace of a Banach space a Banach? 
All I know is that… it is only yes iff it is closed and bounded and contains its limit points…  any good point?

Comment: Subspaces $W$ of Banach spaces are Banach if only if $W$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you Qi Zhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$W$ a subspace of a Banach space $X$ is Banach, i.e. complete, iff $W$ is closed.

*Example of a subspace which is not closed*:

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, complete with the usual norm. Let $W=\mathbb{Q}$, which is a subspace of $X$ but is not complete.

Comment: But Banach spaces are conventionally vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, so this is not really a good example.